# Verb that means "to make an excuse"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

It's on the tip of my tongue.

I think there's a word (possibly ending in -ate) which means, loosely, "to make excuses".

Not in the sense found [here](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/to%20make%20an%20excuse) of "decline", but meaning to try and justify something.  It doesn't necessarily have to have the connotation that these excuses are bad ones, or that the action was in fact unjustified, but it could do.

For example, "I accused him of not delivering, but rather than apologise he X"

Comment: There's **exculpate** or, more likely, **exonerate**. You'd say he **exonerated himself**.

Comment: 'he excused himself'? otherwise 'fudged it', 'wangled his way out', 'sidestepped'.. how formal is the word?

Comment: " He excused the [thing] by [doing something] "

Comment: Redirected blame? Passed the buck?

Comment: If the self-excusing relies on BS, there's prevaricate. It's more polite than bullshit, yet slimy. At 11 letters, it just might do the trick where it's most needed.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Formal without a doubt.  Rarely heard in day-to-day conversation

Comment: You said the word yourself - *justify*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following words could be used in certain situations:

- **mitigate**, in the sense of attempting to reduce the perceived consequences of an action. I don't think this is a good answer, and it needs some additional words around it,  but at least it ends in "ate".
- **temporize**, where a partial answer is given with the objective of gaining time, e.g. ...instead of apologizing or explaining, he *temporized*. "We'll look up the background in our files.  Then we should talk again..."

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it was a valiant effort.  In the end, the word I was searching for was "recriminate", but that has a narrower definition than what I gave in the original question, so it's not surprising that no one got it!

Comment: Thanks!  To be honest, *recriminate* did not occur to me at all.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of anything better (especially ending with -ate) than

> **exonerate** *verb*
>
> (of an official body) absolve (someone) from blame for a fault or wrongdoing.
>   ‘an inquiry exonerated those involved’
>   ‘they should exonerate these men from this crime’

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exonerate)

I think the best way to word your sample sentence would then be:

> I accused him of not delivering, but rather than apologising he exonerated himself.

Comment: Exonerate means "prove" rather than "make an argument", so isn't really a fit here.  But thanks for your contribution

Comment: Certainly "exonerate" has an implication that the person _really isn't_ to blame rather than merely _claims_ not to be. However, since we're using "exonerate _himself_" I think that it's pretty clear that that is not implied in this case. Not ending with -ate, but there is also **rationalise**.

Comment: Another possibility, but perhaps with the same problem as "exonerate" is "vindicate".

Comment: It has the same issue yes